# Скажите как сделать чтобы элемент хорошо отражался на разных экранах

Tags: css3, html5

```css
.h2{
color: #717171
font-family: "Proxima Nova - Semibold"
font-size: 24px
font-weight: 400
text-align: right
position: relative
};
.h2:before{
content: ''
display: block
position: absolute
width: 2px
height: 31px
background-color: #e7e7e7
left: 485px
top: -7px
};
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section class="service-section">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-7">
    <h2 class="h2">
     наши услуги
    </h2>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Скажите как зафиксировать элемент чтобы на разных разрешениях выглядело одинаково[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: если вам нужно одинаково, то нужно использовать "резиновою" верстку. Либо мадиа...очень много медиа. А так будет в принципе одинаково, за исклбчением например `margin-left:auto` у класса `container`

Comment: @Виталий Шебаниц спасибо я уже решил через flex

Comment: @Виталий Шебаниц  скажите резиновую верстку начинается с mobile ?

Comment: Вопрос не понятен...резиновая верстка - это когда ширина блоков у вас записана в процентном соотношении

Comment: @Виталий Шебаниц скажите пожалуйста если я не задаю ширину или высоту элементу будет считаться резиновым ?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/959278/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B5

Comment: @Виталий Шебаниц Вы знаете как это сделать https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/959278/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B5